# Disabling Multi Touch Gestures in Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS Desktop

Tags: touchpad, ubuntu-touch, multi-touch, gestures

I am Using a Critical Application which needs to be on the screen all the time , and user should not be able to logoff or should not be able to acess any other Application , The Device is equipped with Touch Panel USB Type . However the ubuntu has Default Multitouch Gestures which allows the user to Change Placement of the Window of runnimg application with 3 Finger , Also the Pinch Fuction with 5 Fingers allow user to Have Access to BackGround applicatio ,
I would Appreciate if someone help to findout a way to Disable the Multi Touch Gestures ( Allowing Single TAP function Only with Touch).

Comment: I'd first check your system is fully updated (an updated *xenial* system will report itself as 16.04.7) and consider upgrading as 16.04 is in it's last days of *standard* support (and will very soon be off-topic here) - https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2021/03/13/extended-security-maintenance-for-ubuntu-16-04-xenial-xerus-begins-april-30-2021/  FYI: 16.04.5 ISO was released in August-2018 (https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2018/08/02/ubuntu-16-04-5-lts-released/) but installed systems got it before that date, you could be years behind on upgrades & security fixes if you're using 16.04.4

Comment: Hi ..Thanks for the Reply , The system has been upgraded to 16.04.7.., Problem of Multi Touch Gestures Remains Un resolved ..

Comment: [Ubuntu 16.04 LTS has reached the end of it's *standard* support life](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2021/03/13/extended-security-maintenance-for-ubuntu-16-04-xenial-xerus-begins-april-30-2021/) thus is now off-topic here unless your question is specific to helping you move to a supported release of Ubuntu.  Ubuntu 16.04 ESM support is available, but not on-topic here, see https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic  See also https://ubuntu.com/blog/ubuntu-16-04-lts-transitions-to-extended-security-maintenance-esm

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.Gestures windows-drag-pinch false
gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.Gestures dash-tap false
gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.Gestures launcher-drag false
```